# How can I switch orientation at runtime in Eclipse Emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have been doing testing with my android project, and I have built orientation change functionality into my app, but when I change the orientation in Eclipses emulator, it remains in portrait(or landscape depending on how it started).

EDIT**: The emulator itself rotates, but the APP doesnt.

And the `public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration c)` method is never called.

Yes I have put `android:configChanges="orientation"` in my manifest

I would prefer not to have to buy a phone for testing, so help would be graciously appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Emulator orientation cannot be changed by orientation change events and therefore this question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

pres ctrl+f12 you will be able to get the emulator rotated. Emulator will by defaul will not rotate it will just present the view

Answer (score 0):

use numbers 9 and 7 in keyboard numpad

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the runtime but try CTRL + F12.